# Android App tablet compaitablity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on an app for my University, and everything is working great. Except Tablet compatibility. Below is my AndroidManifest file, does anypne have suggestions on what is wrong. The play store says "This app is not compatible with this device"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rmu.mobile.tcdev"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="0.0.3" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" 
        android:required="False"
        />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
        />
    <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
    />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/RealTheme"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.rmu.mobile.tcdev.RMULayoutsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- <activity android:name=".ActionItemsSampleActivity" /> -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:required` is not a valid attribute for [uses-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html). Instead, you must add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what the device you are running on it has installed. You have a min SDK version of 8. There are many devices that are running below that. Also, taking a look at my own code, the "supports screen" category is not 100% necessary.

Comment: The device in Question is a Nexus 7. But no tablet we have checked will work, regardless of SDK version.